# Spreadsheets that use a functional-programming language

Tags: functional-programming, spreadsheet

I'd like to know if there exists a spreadsheet application which uses an existing functional-programming language to define functions.

I've already heard about [Resolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/products/resolver-one/) which uses python, but I'm more interested in anything which uses a purely functional language like Haskell.

Thanks

Comment: Too exotic ... why would you want that? Excel is like a bad, heavy, single-threaded GUI library with many holes which tries to do its own thing. I do not think that Haskell is practical enough to have substantial GUI libraries ...

Comment: @ipthnc Where did he say anything about Excel?

Comment: Good luck finding one that uses a pure language. There are only a few in existence, and impure functional languages in the Lisp and ML families are much more popular. Python, of course, is not a functional language at all — it's an imperative OO language that happens to have first-class functions.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd say Excel is single-threaded.   I kinda find that hard to believe.   When I run Excel on a computer with a ton of cores, it tells me at the bottom of the app how many cores it's using.   Are they doing that without threads?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spreadsheets are quite a popular application among functional programmers.  They have been a recurring theme in papers over the years.  Some of the more memorable papers include

- [Spreadsheet Functional Programming](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1194878) by David Wakeling (2007).
- [Forms/3](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=968486.968487&coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&CFID=69598404&CFTOKEN=64518855) by Margaret Burnett and many others (2001)
- [Implementing Function Spreadsheets](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1370847.1370867&coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&CFID=69598404&CFTOKEN=64518855) by Peter Sestoft (2008)

You can also read about [an effort to make Excel more functional](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.3.4538).

For each of these papers I have either read the paper or heard a talk based on the papers.  None of the papers is fabulous but all of them are good.  I think the one with the most interesting ideas is by Sestoft—and his experimental results are pretty amazing.

Answer (score 2):

If you count [JavaScript as a functional programming language](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+functional+programming) you can use [Google Web Scripts for Google Spreadsheets](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/overview.html) :)

Comment: I suspect Javascript is the most strongly functional language you'll find. Also note that there are compilers for Haskell and OCaml to Javascript.

Comment: Haskell isn't "the most strongly functional language"?

Comment: @mipadi: It's not that Haskell isn't functional; it's that I don't expect to find a real spreadsheet application that uses Haskell to define functions.

Answer (score 2):

There's Scheme In A Grid (http://siag.nu/siag/), but it's looking kind of out of date.

There's also Haxcel (http://www.mrtc.mdh.se/projects/Haxcel/), which was a thesis project.

If you want to do functional programming in a spreadsheet the best practical choice is probably Resolver One, as you've already noted. (I would say "functional programming" in this context means first-class functions that work with other spreadsheet functions and the sheet itself - i.e. you could write a function that returns a function, call it and have the result go in a cell for yet other cells to call, etc. I don't know if OpenOffice and Google Docs will do that.)

A colleague and I have been working on a little project to do this within Excel, using a syntax very close to Excel formulas. I described it briefly in a comment on Roy MacLeans's VBA Blog:

http://roymacleanvba.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/domain-specific-languages-%e2%80%93-part-2/#comment-130

It's changed some since I posted that, but if you want to call our very-minimal syntax a "language", it's certainly "pure". (And I'm still planning to release it to the vast universe of FP-implemented-in-VBA enthusiasts, but stuff keeps coming up...)

Answer (score 0):

There is herculus.io

But it seems down currently.

The guide describes a concept I find very interesting: https://app.herculus.io/doc/guides/app/